# What is my mistake here? I was trying to find F/G factor here

Tags: economics

I was trying to derive an expression for F/G factor here for homework. I have attached my working in this picture. I always end up with a (1+i) in the numerator which is not in the actual formula. What am I doing wrong here? I have been working on this all day long and have not been able to figure it out.
[image: I always end up with a (1+i) in the numerator which is not in the actual formula.]

[image: For n=3]

[image: Actual formula in book...]

Comment: Write out all terms in the case $n=2$ or $n=3$.

Comment: i did  it for n=3.

Comment: Should be right. Probably a mistake in that "actual formula" then.

Comment: It could be a difference in assumptions. For example, if you have an account earning an interest rate $i$ compounded annually, and you make a deposit of amount $G$ every year, you'll end up with a greater balance (greater by a factor of $1+i$) if you make those deposits at the beginning of each year than if you make them at the end of each year.

Comment: ah i see that could be the case.

Comment: What is the actual formula? Are both calculations your attempts or is the first one a given solution?

Comment: i added the formula found online and in my book.